# Ho to use a Celery worker

Tags: python, redis, celery, python-3.6, worker

I'm try to fetch some data from my app by a Celery worker and a Redis server but I get this error:

```
    Unrecoverable error: SyntaxError('invalid syntax', ('/home/g-luca/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py', 22, 19, 'from . import async, base\n'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/g-luca/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 42, in __get__
    return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
KeyError: 'backend'
```

What I see from the output is that Celery is under python3.7 while I set-up all the things and run the application with python 3.6.

Comment: Did you activate virtualenv before executing celery worker? Something like `source path/to/venv/activate && celery worker ...`.

Comment: @illagrenan No, I didn't. I'm just following instructions given by our professor, and there is no mention about virtualenv, but i cannot ask him specifications, I should ble able to make it work. We are working with Flask and Skeleton and we applies some requirements before arriving this point. I've omitted them because I think there are not relevant.